# Animated Teenage boy growing black wings?

Tags: story-identification, animation

I remember this animation from my childhood about a young teenage boy and his sister/girlfriend who were angels. The boy who had blond hair (if I remember clearly) AND was really excited to get his wings like other angels (perhaps). I remember that his sister warned him that if he gets involved in evil doings and doesn't behave right, black wings will grow on him.

The next thing I remember is that eventually he sees black little wings growing on him and he tries hard to hide them from others....

I was just so young and I don't remember much but I really hope some of you might remember and save me from this terrible frustration ... Thank you

Comment: When and where did you see this? Do you remember any other detail that could help people recognizing it? Consider having a look at ["how to ask a good story-id question"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for some guidance.

Comment: Probably not the anime you look for, but wings becoming black as a sign of sin and hiding that difference are a major topic of [Haibane Renmei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haibane_Renmei). What doesn't match: The protagonist is a girl, and the one who tells her about the meaing of black wings is not her sister but her caretaker and mentor. Like the protagonist she is a Haibane, one of the angel-like creatures giving the series its title, and also like the protagonist her wings turn black and need to be bleached to hide the mark of sin.